# How to create a general purpose data tokenizer in C++?

Tags: c++, string, parsing, c++11

So, say I have a data file with regular data formatted similarly to this:

```
[42,6,9,56,1337]
[220,9001,15,22,35]
[127,0,0,1,8080]
```

I read each line in as a string, and I have a tokenizer that accepts an input string, mulitple delimiters as another string, and a reference to a `vector<string>` for storing the output into.

```
// given a string with delimiters inside, parse it into
//  individual tokens stored in a vector<string>
void tokenize(const string& str, vector<string>& tokens,
              const string& delimiters = " ") {
  auto last_pos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, 0);      // first token
  auto curr_pos = str.find_first_of(delimiters, last_pos);   // next delim

  while (curr_pos != str_end || last_pos != str_end) {
    tokens.emplace_back(str.substr(last_pos, curr_pos - last_pos));    
    last_pos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, curr_pos);  // next token
    curr_pos = str.find_first_of(delimiters, last_pos);      // next delim
  }
}

int main() {
  ifstream fs{"data"};
  string tmp{""};
  const string delims{"[,]"};
  vector<string> tokens;
  //vector<int> tokens;
  //vector<double> tokens;

  while (getline(fs, tmp)) tokenize(tmp, tokens, delims);

  cout << tokens << endl;
}
```

So far OK. But then I wanted to use the actual datatypes to work with instead of strings, so I wrote a couple of numeric wrapper functions that take the `vector<string>` and convert it into (say) a `vector<int>`. Then I realized these were basically duplicates of one another.

```
// int wrapper
void tokenize(const string& str, vector<int>& tokens,
              const string& delimiters = " ") {
  vector<string> str_tokens;
  tokenize(str, str_tokens, delims);

  for (const auto& e : str_tokens)
    tokens.emplace_back(stoi(e));  // ints    
}
```

Then I tried creating another general wrapper, but I got hung up on the problems that
**A**) I wasn't sure how to change between standard library conversion functions, and
**B**) Figured it would also try to execute with string T's as well which wasn't the original idea.

After a little further thought I realized I might just be doing it wrong and should somehow try to use just one generic function instead. But I'm at a loss to see a way to do it.

Here's the program listing. The data is stored as a local file named just "data".
http://pastebin.com/dRAXRWa3

Comment: Is there any reason for writing your own tokenizer? Why not just use a library, like boost::spirit?

Comment: You can try reading the source code for awk or a CSV parser, since these are examples of general purpose data tokenizers written in C or C++. C is different than C++ but I'm sure the code will be helpful.

Comment: @Rostislav Because I'm trying to learn details of creating my own C++ programs.

Comment: @djechlin Thanks, I appreciate the advice. I'll look into your suggestions.

Comment: Makes sense. I just wanted to make sure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical example where templates come into play. The only culprit is that you need to call different functions to transform strings to data types. This can be solved with templates as well though. Here's a working commented example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Declare a generic conversion function...
template<typename T>
T stoT(const std::string& s);

// ... and specialize it for the data types you need to convert
// int specialization
template<>
int stoT(const std::string& s)
{
    return stoi(s);
}

// double specialization
template<>
double stoT(const std::string& s)
{
    return stod(s);
}

template<typename T>
void tokenize(const string& str, vector<T>& tokens,
              const string& delimiters = " ") {
    vector<string> str_tokens = {"1", "2", "3"};

    // Prepare the output - clear and reserve the space to avoid multiple allocations
    str_tokens.clear();
    tokens.reserve(str_tokens.size());

    // Transform the strings to your data types
    std::transform(str_tokens.begin(), str_tokens.end(), std::back_inserter(tokens), stoT<T>);

}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vi;
    tokenize("", vi); 
    for (const auto& v : vi) { std::cout << v << " "; }

    std::cout << "\n";

    std::vector<double> vd;
    tokenize("", vd); 
    std::cout << std::fixed;
    for (const auto& v : vd) { std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << v << " "; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is great! I will use your example to improve my own somewhat similar solution which I came up with also.

Answer (score 0):

So a buddy linked me to this page at isocpp: [template specialization](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-specialization-piecemeal), and I was able to come up with a workable approach of my own (though Rostislav's is obviously better).

I created a

```
T decode<T>(const string& x) { }
```

set of specializations, then templatized the tokenizer() function and changed one line of code.

```
tokens.emplace_back(decode<T>(str.substr(last_pos, curr_pos - last_pos)));
```

It seems to work pretty much as I intended. Now I'll improve on it with your advice SO.

Thanks.

(edit) Here's a corrected version.
http://pastebin.com/reRMc2G3